# Is there any difference when compilers implements C inline function in different platforms

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I was told that the implementation for C inline functions in different platforms (e.g. Mips vs x86) is a little different. For example, inline function for one of them (Mips or x86) still allocates stack and thus not so efficient. Is it true? What are all the difference? Thanks

Comment: How a compiler decides to implement particular optimizations is not set by the standard - so you can expect differences between different compilers on the same platform, and between the same compiler on different platforms. I don't think it is possible to give a "definitive" answer. My I ask why you are asking? Usually, "micro optimization" is more effort than it is worth. Do you have a case where that might not be true?

Comment: I need to implement set/get methods to access the fields of the structures, pretty like what we do in OO programming. In the consideration of the efficiency, inline function is my last choice. But I was told that inline function may not be so efficient in x86 platform. I'm not sure if that's true and I'm wondering what are all the difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not guaranteed that every function will be inlined when you declare it inline (it is just a suggestion to the compiler). Hence for *any* architecture the functions that aren't inlined will be treated as normal functions, and hence the push & pop from the stack when you call them (like any normal non-inlined function)

And it is pretty much dependent upon how your compiler is configured. For eg, [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) has flags like:

**-finline-functions**
Consider all functions for inlining, even if they are not declared inline. The compiler heuristically decides which functions are worth integrating in this way.

**-finline-limit=n**
By default, GCC limits the size of functions that can be inlined. This flag allows coarse control of this limit. n is the size of functions that can be inlined in number of pseudo instructions.

**--param name=value**
In some places, GCC uses various constants to control the amount of optimization that is done. For example, GCC does not inline functions that contain *more than a certain number of instructions*. You can control some of these constants on the command line using the --param option.

Comment: Also, the details of code generation are determined by an individual compiler, rather than being shared by all compilers on a given platform... and I seriously doubt that anyone has made the e4ffort to test every available compiler and constructed a table which gives "all the differences". Absolute statements are always inherently false, including this one -- if it really matters to you, test the compilers you're interested in with the specific code you're interested in, on the specific platform you're interested in.

Comment: I understand that it is not guaranteed. But if the compiler decides to inline it, will the implementation differs cross the platforms?

Comment: Check the gcc link I have mentioned above, the rules are made by the compiler rather than the hardware/architecture. And obviously the underlying machine resources do play a part in deciding what is the level of support to inlining. For eg supporting  max N level of nested inline functions etc.

Comment: To sum it up, it is pretty much your compiler settings and available hardware resources rather than *type* of your platform.

Comment: +1 for valiant effort to answer what is, in essence, an unanswerable question.

Comment: @Floris: I'll take that as a complement! :)

Comment: @brokenfoot - that is how it was intended.